# Potree : Save user interactions

Tags: las, point-cloud, viewer, laz, potree

I am a new user of Potree and I would like to know if anyone has already an idea or found a way to save a user's interactions on Potree and use them again.
For example: if the user added an annotation or changed the map colors of his point cloud, how can I get his changes and save them in my database?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've made any progress on this, it's something I'm working on building into my system at the moment. A good place to start is the export tools at the top of the Scene section in the sidebar. Those exports will contain a lot of the information about measurements, annotations, etc, that you could then import into your database. The Potree export is probably the one that would be most useful but you can open them in any text editor and see what information that have.

If those don't have what you're looking for then you'll have to start playing with the Javascript code to pull out what you're after and pass it on to your server using something like AJAX.